# Using Github actions for checking security of response headers doesn't work

Tags: github-actions, cicd, websecurity

I am using GitHub Actions to create a workflow that will Analyse HTTP response headers of my website and provide me the results, similar to https://securityheaders.com/.

I am using https://github.com/marketplace/actions/analyse-your-http-response-headers but I am getting this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqI4z.png)

This is my workflow:

```yaml
name: security_header
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - env/sbox
      - env/qa
      - env/production
jobs:
  test_response_headers:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: marcuslindblom/security-headers
      - name: response-header-security-check
        id: security-check
        uses: marcuslindblom/security-headers@v1.2.0
        with:
          url: https://someurl.com
          # url: ${{ secrets.SECURITY_HEADERS_URL }}
          followRedirects: true # This is optional
          grade: A
```

Comment: I just forked and fixed its `entrypoint.sh` script. Please test and verify it on your side i.e. `uses: iamazeem/security-headers@main`. I'll push to the upstream once it's verified from your side.

Comment: @Azeem I am new to collaboration, also I am not the author of the repo, can you suggest what I should do next

Comment: @Azeem that warning is now gone

Comment: Is it working fine now? No error or warning?

Comment: @Azeem Yeah that error is gone, but my job is still failing because when I run my website URL through securityheaders.com it is failing. thanks so much bro

Comment: @Azeem can you please explain how this is working now ?

Comment: Good to hear that. PR created (https://github.com/marcuslindblom/security-headers/pull/7). Commented on your issue also. Keep an eye on its merge and release. You may switch back to using it once it's merged and released.

Comment: Why is it failing now? Did you check its logs? Are you seeing this error "**Please use an API Key from https://securityheaders.com/api**"?

Comment: @Azeem No I dont see that error, can you please explain why only the second `uses` was changed and not the first one ?

Comment: The first one in checkout is redundant. You don't need that.

Comment: BTW, you can simply use `curl` directly and get on with it. See the API docs: https://securityheaders.com/api/docs/.

Comment: For example, you can run `curl -H "x-api-key: <API-KEY>" "https://api.securityheaders.com/?q=<URL>&hide=on&followRedirects=on" | jq -r '.summary.grade'` and use this output accordingly. See jq example here: https://jqplay.org/s/2VGAng3E0nB.

Comment: **FYI**: I have recently released this composite action (https://github.com/iamazeem/security-headers-action). You might want to give it try. Thanks!

Comment: @Azeem say this action is ran on a PR, can we output/comment the result of the action in the same PR.

Comment: You may use some existing action to comment on the PR or use the GitHub CLI i.e. [`gh pr comment`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_comment).